# How can I enable .docx, .xlsx etc. at the end of file names?

Tags: windows-explorer

I want to see `.docx`, `.xlsx`, etc. at the end of my filenames.  This is currently hidden.

How do I make this appear?

Comment: You might find [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=show+file+extensions) useful. This is a very basic operation, and very easily found.

Answer (score 1):

Go To Start, search for "File Explorer Options", go To View Tab,"Hide extensions for known file types", uncheck It, apply Then OK, Done

Answer (score 1):

You can do this from within a current Windows File Explorer window.

For Windows 8, 8.1, and 10, this can be accomplished by clicking the 'View' tab, and checking the 'File Name extensions' box. Here is a visual overview:

1. When viewing a folder, click the 'View' tab:
   [image: Folder with highlight over the 'View' tab]
2. On the View tab, you should be able to see 'File Name Extensions':
   [image: View Tab with circle around 'File name extensions']
3. Check the box, you should immediately see `docx`, `xlsx` and other file types appear:
   [image: After checking the box, the file extensions appear]

---

In Windows Vista & 7 the option is more hidden but not too hard to find.

1. From your open Windows Explorer window, click 'Organize'.
2. Click 'Folder and search options' then the 'View' tab
3. Scroll down to find 'Hide extensions for known file types'
4. Uncheck this box and click 'OK'

---

You can read more about enabling filename extensions on [Microsoft's Knowledge Base](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/865219/how-to-show-or-hide-file-name-extensions-in-windows-explorer).

Answer (score 0):

First open "File Explorer" (the classic app that you use to browse your files).

If you are in **Windows 8/10**, at the menu "**View**" mark the square "*File name extensions*" and you will see them again.

In **Windows 7** is similar, I do not remember exactly, open **File** -> "**Organize**" -> "**Advanced Options**" and there is a list, uncheck "*hide extensions of known files*".

Answer (score -1):

You will need to uncheck the option "Hide extensions for known file types" after locating the Folder Options dialog box, available in from within any File Explorer window.

Answer (score -2):

In All Windows Versions:

- Go To Start
- Search For "File Explorer Options"
- Go To View Tab
- Under 'Hide Empty Drives' -> "Hide extensions for known file types"
- UnCheck It
- Click 'Apply' then 'Ok', Done

Comment: "-Go To Start
-Search "For File Explorer Options"" That does not work on Windows 7.